pip installed a package to a cache, should I add it to the PATH
Note: the following was originally posted to the software engineering stack exchange, they closed it and told me to post it here instead.
I recently tried to install pytest with pip, and got the error
WARNING: The scripts py.test.exe and pytest.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

I found several other people with similar issues, installed off PATH for Linux and a similar issue for windows, (not stack exchange), among others. Both say that I need to add this to the path if I want to run the pytest command. However my location is inside what is labeled as a CACHE, which seems like a good way to have it stop working at some point.
My exact questions are:

Is it going to cause bugs/ other problems to add the cache to my PATH? (I am particularly worried about the cache being flushed at some point in the future)
Is it a bad idea, style wise, to add the cache to my PATH? (If this is too much of an opinion based question, please say so and I can remove it.)
If it is a problem, what should I do instead to allow me to execute the cli commands?

other notes:
I am on windows
Edit as requested by the comments here is the result of the path section of python -m sysconfig:
Paths: 
        data = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"
        include = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include"
        platinclude = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include"      
        platlib = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages"
        platstdlib = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib"
        purelib = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages"
        scripts = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Scripts"
        stdlib = "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib"


I am not a Windows user, but this Scripts location seems strange to me. And I am not sure how to debug this. Maybe adding the Paths: part of the python -m sysconfig output to your question could help with the debugging. -- Anyway I find it also strange that you do not seem to be using a virtual environment. Basically every pip install command should be done in a virtual environment. I feel like pytest in particular, there is not much reason to not install it in a virtual environment.

@sinoroc I added the paths section. I dont think the standards are the same for windows as it is for linux, but I am not sure about that.

If we look at the value for scripts, there is no LocalCache in that path location, and that is more like I would expect. I do not know where that LocalCache part came from, but it is suspicious. You might want to investigate that and fix it. -- Also, once again I recommend you use virtual environments one way or another.
